# beginner spring batch queries to understand itemstream and some concept

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am new to Spring batch and I need to write a spring batch application which will read student registration data from DB table and produce a PDF datasheet for each student . So I need to write an SQL query which will pull data from DB and populate a pre defined PDF template with that data and store the pdf file in different folder as per student study location.

So far I have learned Spring batch has 3 interfaces called- ItemReader, ItemWriter and ItemProcessor. May I know in which interface implementation I need to write which function of my application?

Also, I have come accross another interface called ItemStream. May I know why should I incorporate it?

Comment: For this type of question your best choice is to read official SB documentation in association with some examples (there's a lot of place on net where you can find them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first understand how Spring Batch is designed. Find it here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/domain.html

There are 2 type of batch operations, one containing chunk and other tasket. We will be using chuck. Build your application as follows.

- Using [JdbcCursorItemReader](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/database/JdbcCursorItemReader.html), read data from database.
- Use a ItemProcessor if you want any modification in your data
- Implement ItemWriter. See reference from here: https://github.com/dpitt/spring-batch-report-writer

Answer (score 0):

> So far I have learned Spring batch has 3 interfaces called-
>   ItemReader, ItemWriter and ItemProcessor. May I know in which
>   interface implementation I need to write which function of my
>   application?

You need to create one Job. This Job will have one Step. And Step will have ItemReader, ItemWriter and ItemProcessor.

1. `ItemReader` will read from DB and map it to some POJO.
2. `ItemProcessor` will take this POJO and process on that and return the
   processed POJO (or some different POJO).
3. `ItemWriter` will get this updated POJO and there you can write to
   template PDF and save it to the folder as you want.

Comment: why we are not doing everything in ItemReader?

Comment: That is how Spring batch is designed & it is meant to be used in this way. It has divided the specific task in different interface. Reader, Processor & Writer. If you want to do everything in ItemReader then why do you even need to use Spring batch at all? You can simply write in normal Java.